# display triangle programitaclly in NSOPENGLVIEW

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Adding NSWindow and NSOpenGlView programmatically is displaying wrong output inside the window, here is the my code:

```
NSWindow* hWindow  = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
                                                     styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask
                                                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                         defer:YES  ];
    _m_window = hWindow;
    [hWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
    [hWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: hWindow];



NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] =
{
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
    // Must specify the 3.2 Core Profile to use OpenGL 3.2
    NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,
    NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
    0
};

NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pf = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs];

HanyViewer* viewer = [[HanyViewer alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 100, 100, 400,400 ) pixelFormat:pf];
_m_view = viewer;
[viewer setWantsLayer:YES];

[hWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
[hWindow setOpaque:YES];
[hWindow.contentView addSubview:viewer];



@implementation HanyViewer

-(void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawAnObject();
    glFlush();
}


static void drawAnObject ()
{
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.85f, 0.35f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        glVertex3f(  0.0,  0.6, 0.0);
        glVertex3f( -0.2, -0.3, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(  0.2, -0.3 ,0.0);
    }
    glEnd();
}

@end
```

the result is a view inside the window with background color or some garbage inside the view

Comment: You probably need something like this in the app delegate code: `[self.viewer setNeedsDisplay: YES];`

Comment: that is the entire code, and it is not helping..

Comment: If this is the entire code, no wonder it can't run. It can't even compile. Where are your class and interface declarations, where's the delegate, initializations, `main()`?...